# Converting to datetime resulting in NA

Tags: r, datetime, dataframe, posixlt

I have a data frame with the following attributes and fields:

```
print(sapply(df1, typeof))

SurveyUserStart 
      "integer" 
print(df1)

 SurveyUserStart
1 2016-10-17 08:55:13
2 2016-04-24 14:31:12
3 2016-09-01 15:17:54
4 2016-07-20 11:26:56
```

I am trying to convert this column `SurveyUserStart` to `datetime` format. I have tried various methods below but I have always resulted in `NA`

```
df1$SurveyUserStart <- as.POSIXlt(as.character(df1$SurveyUserStart), format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
df1$SurveyUserStart <- as.character(df1$SurveyUserStart, format="%m/%d/%Y  %H:%M:%S %p")
```

Comment: `as.POSIXct(x = "2016-10-17 08:55:13", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")` OR `anytime::anytime("2016-10-17 08:55:13")` OR `lubridate::ymd_hms("2016-10-17 08:55:13")` . You'll need `anytime` package for the second one and `lubridate` package for the third one

Comment: You probably have a factor. Learn to use 'class' rather than 'typeof'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already stated in the comments it is important in which order you give your format info to the function. If your date `2016-10-17 08:55:13` this means you have year-month-day hour:minute:second. If you want to transform to a date you have to give exactly this information yo the function in your case:

```
as.POSIXct(x = as.character(df3$SurveyUserStart), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Please note that if you use the POSIXct function you also have to choose the right separator (in your case a -) between the different formats.
If you use the package `lubridate` this is not needed anymore, however you still have to give the right order of your date object in the functionname (y=year, m=month, d=day, ...) which leads to the following function:

```
ymd_hms(as.character(df3$SurveyUserStart))
```